# In Dual Boot with Windows 11 computer boots directly to windows then on next boot or restart shows Grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

In my dual boot of ubuntu 22.04.3 and windows 11, on first startup/boot, it goes straight to windows.

When I switch off and start again, it then does the right thing and shows the grub menu for me to either select windows/ubuntu.

If I am in Ubuntu and restart, it restarts into windows, if I am in windows and restart, it restarts into Ubuntu.

Basically on each restart it alternates between directly booting into windows and booting to the grub menu where i can select ubuntu/windows.

It frustrating as each time I put on my pc, I have to switch it on a second time for me to access the grub menu and ubuntu boots.

This started after I force switched off my pc when a dropbox install froze my pc for a while.

I'm using an ssd drive and this is the only problem i have faced since that day. The ssd is partitioned into two with each drive having a different os.

Comment: Thank you learnt from this however was not the problem. Solution was to arrange the boot order in the bios, a solution I saw before and didnt work when I implemented it. However tried it again and worked this time around.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the boot priority order in your bios setting and make Ubuntu in first position,this will allow Ubuntu boot loader(grub) to open first.

Comment: Thank you so much. Tried this again and this time around it worked. I'm thinking I failed to save changes in the bios the last time i tried this solution as this time its solved the issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: you are always welcome